# `punycode` module / deprecated

Tags: next.js, punycode

On a nextJS app, when running this command:

```
 % npm run build
```

I just got this message:

```
 ✓ Linting and checking validity of types    
 ✓ Collecting page data    
(node:2225) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated.
Please use a userland alternative instead.
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
   Generating static pages (0/6)  [=   ](node:2224) [DEP0040] DeprecationWarning: The `punycode` module is deprecated. Please use a userland    alternative instead.
```

But punycode is not something I installed. Actually I don't know what it is.

I noticed it was present in my package-lock.json file; but was not aware of it before this.

I saw on the net that this issue has already appeared, but did not see any clear solution.

Is there any way to handle this problem ?

I could always try something like:

```
npm install punycode
```

But installing something that I don't need, or don't know why I need it feels somewhat weird.

Comment: This exact question has been asked a half-dozen times recently, [and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpunycode%5D+deprecated+npm), but apparently people don't want to repeat the answer as often as the question is repeated.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Wondering what this is or if you need it to run Nextjs 14 optimally.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

solution that worked for me: npm install punycode --save

and then in node_modules go to the directory tr46 > index.js

Replace this: const punycode = require('punycode'); With this: const punycode = require('punycode/');

basically just add a trailing forward slash